# How do I take data from one assignment and use it in specific way in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, range, graphing

In the latter half of a program, I need to plot an equation and some averages from a previous program. Here is the code:

```
Assign6 

coef = polyfit(1:x-1,theAverage,7);

eqFit = [num2str(coef(1)),'*x^7 + ',num2str(coef(2)),'*x^6 + ',num2str(coef(3)),...
    '*x^5 + ',num2str(coef(4)),'*x^4 + ',num2str(coef(5)),'*x^3 + ',num2str(coef(6)),...
    '*x^2 + ',num2str(coef(7)),'*x + ',num2str(coef(8))];

warning off

hold on 

fplot(coef, '-.')
fplot(eqFit, '-.', [1 machines])
title('Graph of Equation and Raw Data')
grid on
xlabel('')
ylabel('')
legend('Equation', 'Raw Data')
xlim tight
```

I need to graph the equation in the template and make sure that the range of x is 1 to how many actual averages there are. Open for suggestions.

Comment: Also, Assign6 is the program that it reads from

Answer (score 0):

Normal Matlab scripts store their variables in a common global memory called the Workspace. You can just access them there by their name. The Matlab IDE should also have a window showing you all the variables in the Workspace, their type and their size.